# The Onclick in AlertDialog doesn't work

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent

I am trying to create a sudoku board and when you press one of the empty buttons it will show
you an alert dialog with 10 buttons that contains the numbers 1-9 end an empty one;
when i press on one of the buttons in the dialog nothing happens.

the game code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setView(View.inflate(this, R.layout.activity_dialog, null));
alert.show();
Intent e=getIntent();
int s=e.getIntExtra("number", 0);
```

the dialog code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);
        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        button4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        button4.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dialog, menu);
        return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Button b=(Button)v;
        if(b==button1)
        {
                button1.setText("hay");
                Intent i=new Intent(this,EasyGame.class);
                i.putExtra("number", 1);
                startActivity(i);
        }
        else
        {
                if(b==button2)
                {
                        Intent i=new Intent(this,EasyGame.class);
                        i.putExtra("number", 2);
                        startActivity(i);
                }
                else
                {
                        if(b==button3)
                        {
                                Intent i=new Intent(this,EasyGame.class);
                                i.putExtra("number", 3);
                                startActivity(i);
                        }
                        else
                        {


                                if(b==button4){
                                        Intent i=new Intent(this,EasyGame.class);
                                        i.putExtra("number", 4);
                                        startActivity(i);
                                }
```

Comment: You cannot expect people to read through your hundreds lines of code to find your bug. When you have problem like this, you usually want to reproduce your problem in some kind of trivial case (few lines of code), and if that doesnt help you find the problem, then you post question here...

Comment: I can't really reduce the dialog code but i updated the code of the game to more specific lines

Comment: If you dont want to reduce dialog code, you just create new simple project, with simple alert dialog with one single button, and try if that works.

Comment: My problem isn't with one or two or three buttons it is with more because i need to create the view with more than three buttons

Comment: i reduced this to four buttons

Answer (score 0):

As stated in a comment, you should try to narrow down your problem and only post the most relevant code and we will ask for more if we think its necessary. Also, post the code, formatted by using the toolbar, in your post so we don't have to flip back and forth. You also should accept answers by clicking the check mark next to the appropriate answer when it helps solve your problem. You also should make sure to read all the way through the [Help Section](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

With that being said, I will try to help this time as you are knew. It looks to me like you are showing an `AlertDialog` with `Buttons` by inflating the `layout` then expecting your `Dialog` class to run. This is not how it works. If you want to use that class then instead of using an `AlertDialog` you create an `Intent` and use `startActivityForResult` to start that class and send back a result with `setResult()` in your `Dialog` class. You will then get that result in your first `Acvtivity` with `onActivityRresult()`. So, start your `Intent` when an empty button is clicked instead of `AlertDialog`

```
Intent i = (FirstActivityName.this, Dialog.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

In your `Dialog` class, after the button is clicked you create an `Intent` with an empty constructor and send back say the number that was clicked

```
if(b==button1)
            {
                    Intent i=new Intent();
                    i.putExtra("number", 1);
                    setResult(0);
                    finish();
```

Then in your first `Activity` you will have a method `onActivityResult()` that will be given the `Intent` data that you sent back.

Please read through the [Activity Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) about this which has a good example.

I may be wrong as there was a lot of code to look through but this is what looks like is happening to me.

**Dialog Themed Activity**

Also, you can give your `Activity` the appearance of a `Dialog` by adding the following line to the appropriate `<activity>` tag in your `manifest`

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Comment: Thank you i will read the Help Section i wanted the window to look like an AlertDialog, there is away that i can do that?

Comment: Yes, see the last part of my answer

Comment: @user2747228 You're welcome and good luck. And remember to accept answers that help by clicking the check mark next to it. This shows appreciation for the answerer's time, helps others with similar problems find the solution easier, and will help others want to assist you more.